# Squeeze a div between two other divs when window resizes

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="myClass1">
    </div>
    <div class="myClass2">
    </div>
    <div class="myClass3">
    </div>
    <div class="myClass4">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000;
}

.myClass1 {
    height: 100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myClass2 {
    height: 100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myClass3 {
    height: 100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.myClass4 {
    height: 100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2whdvmw/

I want them all aligned to the right of `main`, but as I resize the window, at some point `myClass1` will reach the left edge of `main` and I want `myClass3` to squeeze between `myClass2` and `myClass4` from that point on.

`myClass1`, `myClass2` and `myClass4` all have fixed size. So when I resize the window, the only width I want to change is the one of `myClass3`.

Is it possible to do this with CSS only?

Comment: Probably. But please provide your current CSS to allow us to help you.

Comment: Can you show a demo?

Comment: I edited with the CSS I have

Comment: So, basically, you want all the divs to stay on the same line, and myClass3 to get smaller and smaller as the space available decreases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex layout.

Specify `flex: 0 1 200px` for your `.myClass3`. This will cause it not to grow but still allow shrinking from a flex-basis width of `200px`. For the rest, specify a `flex: 0 0 200px` to disallow both expanding and shrinking, effectively fixing those at `200px`, as the `.myClass3` shrinks with the decrease in available space.

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a2whdvmw/1/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
.main { width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#000; display: flex;}

.myClass1 {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    height: 100px; background-color: blue;
}

.myClass2 {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    height: 100px; background-color: yellow;
}

.myClass3 {
    flex: 0 1 200px;
    height: 100px; background-color: red;
}

.myClass4 {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    height: 100px; background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="myClass1"></div>
    <div class="myClass2"></div>
    <div class="myClass3"></div>
    <div class="myClass4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed. Do you know if there's a way of setting a max shrinking size? Say for example, that I want to shrink myClass3 until it's 50px. Beyond that point I don't want it to shrink anymore.

Comment: @GustavoAmgarten: Just give a `min-width` -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/a2whdvmw/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try media query..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
  .myClass3{
    width:10%;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps..
Max width and width(%) can be change..

Comment: 50% is a demo value make it 100%.
Whats your current css?

Comment: I added my current CSS